How to plot word cluster in R
I have a matrix like this
dat <- data.frame(word1=c(0.02, -0.1, 0.5, 0.06, -0.03, 0.8),
word2=c(0.7, 0.01, 0.05, -0.23, -0.06, 0.13),
word3=c(-0.52, 0.12, 0.46, 0.08, -0.01, -0.17),
word4=c(0.69, 0.34, -0.11, -0.58, -0.26, 0.35),
word5=c(0.04, 0.08, 0.21, -0.15, -0.04, -0.32),
word6=c(0.39, 0.15, -0.21, 0.59, 0.28, 0.19))
cor(dat)

I want a plot demonstrating that words having higher correlation with each other will cluster together.
I hope to receive some help about this. Many thanks!

Maybe
library(corrr)
network_plot(correlate(dat))



Many thanks for this! @user2974951 That really works for me!

You can consider performing hierarchical clustering, which is just one of many clustering methods. You can do this with one line of code:
plot(hclust(dist(dat,method = "manhattan"),method = "ward.D)) # you can also try euclidean distance method in dist().


What the above code did was to first compute the distance between the objects in dat, utilizing the manhattan distance method, and then convert that into a dendrogram object, which can then be plotted.
I hope this helps!

Many thanks for this! I am just wondering in case the number of words is large (e.g. 300 words), I'm not sure if hierarchical clustering is effective?

Hierarchical clustering can handle that. Another option would be to use the udpipe R package. It has a suite of functions and algorithms for visualizing word clusters
https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/docs/doc5.html
